# Why can't I use unset on copied values inside foreach by reference in PHP7 anymore

Tags: php, foreach, reference, php-7, unset

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
$a = array('a');

foreach ($a as $k => &$v) {
    $a['a'] = $v;
    unset($a[$k]);
}
unset($v);
```

It shows different behavior after server migration from PHP5 to PHP7. Result array contains no values from now on. But it should contain at least one key 'a'.

You can see all the difference on any next link:

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iTw4pAtt)

[Online PHP Shell](https://3v4l.org/6hgrS)

Can anybody explain why exactly PHP has started to delete both old value and new value from array?

Comment: [There have been fixes in php 7 regarding `foreach` and references](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php7_foreach). The proper solution as usual is to just stop using references like that. You shouldn't have been using it anyway.

Comment: As a side note: Your `foreach` loop does the same as `$a = array_combine($a, $a);`

Comment: Yes, I've read [that article](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php7_foreach), but hasn't found explanation for my situation.

I've simplified code to show just a problem.
The whole original code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/BB5cBCZq

Comment: Just drop the `&`, then the code will work as before.

Comment: @NikiC
Thanks, it works. But I need to know why exactly it unsets both keys from array while I want to unset just one old key.

Comment: @IlyaFaleev Because the loop will also iterate over the new elements you add in the loop and these will be deleted as well. The PHP 5 behavior was effectively a bug that occurred in that very specific situation. A very similar code with two array elements will result in the same output on all versions and this is how the loop is generally intended to behave: https://3v4l.org/4JCAI